# Juju - installation of wordpress failed

Tags: 14.04, juju, maas, wordpress

I am using ubuntu 14.04, have juju installed in the MaaS server. 
At first I was having this issue: [image]:

So to solve it, I did `juju ssh`:

`sudo pico /etc/apt/sources.list`

I went [here](https://launchpad.net/~charmers/+archive/ubuntu/charm-helpers) to get the code to add it here /etc/apt/sources.list.

After `sudo apt-get update` I got a error saying **The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available**.

So I did the 2nd method from [here](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2013/04/w-gpg-error-httpppalaunchpadnet-precise.html) and it worked.

Went to my MaaS server and did `juju resolved --retry wordpress/0` and 3mins after I got this error:

```
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:11 INFO unit.wordpress/0.install logger.go:40 Adding system user `statd' (UID 107) ...
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:11 INFO unit.wordpress/0.install logger.go:40 Adding new user `statd' (UID 107) with group `nogroup' ...
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:11 INFO unit.wordpress/0.install logger.go:40 Not creating home directory `/var/lib/nfs'.
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:11 INFO unit.wordpress/0.install logger.go:40 statd start/running, process 6817
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:11 INFO unit.wordpress/0.install logger.go:40 gssd stop/pre-start, process 6851
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:12 INFO unit.wordpress/0.install logger.go:40 idmapd start/running, process 6901
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:12 INFO unit.wordpress/0.install logger.go:40 Setting up php5 (5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.9) ...
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:12 INFO unit.wordpress/0.install logger.go:40 Setting up php-auth-sasl (1.0.6-1) ...
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:12 INFO unit.wordpress/0.install logger.go:40 Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:12 INFO unit.wordpress/0.install logger.go:40 Processing triggers for php5-fpm (5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.9) ...
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:12 INFO unit.wordpress/0.install logger.go:40 php5-fpm stop/waiting
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:12 INFO unit.wordpress/0.install logger.go:40 php5-fpm start/running, process 6945
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:12 INFO unit.wordpress/0.install logger.go:40 Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:12 INFO unit.wordpress/0.install logger.go:40 + modprobe nfs
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:12 INFO unit.wordpress/0.install logger.go:40 + juju-log 'Making /mnt/tmp dir ...'
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:12 INFO unit.wordpress/0.juju-log cmd.go:247 Making /mnt/tmp dir ...
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:12 INFO unit.wordpress/0.install logger.go:40 + mkdir -p /mnt/tmp
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:12 INFO unit.wordpress/0.install logger.go:40 + chmod 1777 /mnt/tmp
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:12 INFO unit.wordpress/0.install logger.go:40 + juju-log 'Making /mnt/logs ...'
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:12 INFO unit.wordpress/0.juju-log cmd.go:247 Making /mnt/logs ...
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:12 INFO unit.wordpress/0.install logger.go:40 + mkdir -p /mnt/logs/php-fpm
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:12 INFO unit.wordpress/0.install logger.go:40 + chmod -R 1777 /mnt/logs
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:12 INFO unit.wordpress/0.install logger.go:40 + juju-log 'Making Ramdisk mount point and config ...'
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:12 INFO unit.wordpress/0.juju-log cmd.go:247 Making Ramdisk mount point and config ...
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:12 INFO unit.wordpress/0.install logger.go:40 + mkdir -p /mnt/ramdisk/proxy-cache
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:12 INFO unit.wordpress/0.install logger.go:40 + mkdir -p /mnt/ramdisk/phpfpm-cache
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:12 INFO unit.wordpress/0.install logger.go:40 + chmod -R 1777 /mnt/ramdisk
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:12 INFO unit.wordpress/0.install logger.go:40 + juju-log 'Installing PHP-FPM pool configs ...'
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:12 INFO unit.wordpress/0.juju-log cmd.go:247 Installing PHP-FPM pool configs ...
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:12 INFO unit.wordpress/0.install logger.go:40 + rm -f /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:12 INFO unit.wordpress/0.install logger.go:40 + install -o root -g root -m 0644 files/charm/php/php5-fpm_pool.d_www.conf /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:12 INFO unit.wordpress/0.install logger.go:40 + rsync -az /var/lib/php5 /mnt/
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:13 INFO unit.wordpress/0.install logger.go:40 + rm -rf /var/lib/php5
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:13 INFO unit.wordpress/0.install logger.go:40 + ln -s /mnt/php5 /var/lib/
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:13 INFO unit.wordpress/0.install logger.go:40 + juju-log 'Creating random secret key ...'
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:13 INFO unit.wordpress/0.juju-log cmd.go:247 Creating random secret key ...
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:13 INFO unit.wordpress/0.install logger.go:40 + '[' '!' -f .wp-secret ']'
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:13 INFO unit.wordpress/0.install logger.go:40 + pwgen -s 10 1
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:13 INFO unit.wordpress/0.install logger.go:40 + juju-log 'Installing wp-cli to make this charm'\''s life a little easier ...'
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:13 INFO unit.wordpress/0.juju-log cmd.go:247 Installing wp-cli to make this charm's life a little easier ...
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:13 INFO unit.wordpress/0.install logger.go:40 + git clone https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli.git /usr/src/wp-cli
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:13 INFO unit.wordpress/0.install logger.go:40 Cloning into '/usr/src/wp-cli'...
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:34 INFO unit.wordpress/0.install logger.go:40 fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection refused
unit-wordpress-0[1322]: 2015-05-25 17:20:34 ERROR juju.worker.uniter.operation runhook.go:86 hook "install" failed: exit status 128
```

[image]

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the important error is:

```
logger.go:40 fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection refused
```

This suggests that the maas node doesn't have a connection to the internet. Or that github was unavailable (I think it was suffering a ddos around the time of this post)